# How create client in whmcs when a new client is created in freshbooks?

Tags: whmcs, freshbooks-api

I want to make a client in WHMCS when a new client is added to FreshBooks. The reverse I have done successfully. Basically I want to sync clients from FreshBooks to WHMCS. Where is the webhook topic in new FreshBooks API?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working at FreshBooks - we recently added Webhooks to the new FreshBooks API, and you can see the documentation for this [here](https://www.freshbooks.com/api/webhooks).

You should be able to register for client create, update, etc, no problem!